# How to use Recurrence Rule for Google Calendar deep link IOS

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, deep-linking

I have an mobile web app targeting IOS that does **two** potential things:

If the user **does NOT have the google calendar app installed:** We open a link to add an event to the web version of google calendar.

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?text=event+title&dates=20210718T080010/20210718T083010&ctz=America/Mexico_City&details=book+details&recur=RRULE%3AFREQ%3DWEEKLY%3BCOUNT%3D11%3BBYDAY%3DSU%2CMO%2CTU%2CWE%2CTH%2CFR%2CSA%3B
```

And if the user **DOES** have the google calendar app installed, we open a DEEP LINK to add the event directly to their google calendar app.

E.G

```
com.google.calendar://?action=create&text=event+title&dates=20210718T080010/20210718T083010&ctz=America/Mexico_City&details=book+details&recur=RRULE%3AFREQ%3DWEEKLY%3BCOUNT%3D11%3BBYDAY%3DSU%2CMO%2CTU%2CWE%2CTH%2CFR%2CSA%3B
```

And testing on Safari, that all works EXCEPT - the recurrence rule doesn't seem to work for the deep link! The recurring section is just empty.

(The recurrence rule is this part `recur=RRULE%3AFREQ%3DWEEKLY%3BCOUNT%3D11%3BBYDAY%3DSU%2CMO%2CTU%2CWE%2CTH%2CFR%2CSA%3B`)

**Am I doing something wrong?**

---

...Further Notes if you're curious:

**1:** The recurrence rules are a little hard to read because they are all websafe, but they look like this

```
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=5;UNTIL=20210701T160000Zs
```

**2:** I *would* just work around this problem by opening the web link in all situations, BUT if the google calendar app is installed it intercepts the web links, and then just takes you to the main calendar and does nothing

**3:** You should be able to open the above links on your ios device and see the behavior that I'm talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further research, it appears that the Google Calendar app simply does NOT support recurrence rules on deep linking :(